# How to create entry for 2 or more entity sets via OdataModel.create in UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a Odata service with 4 entity types - Address, CC, Header, Item, Comments.
After the user presses the "Order" button, I want to create an entry in backend using this service. There is a header and associated items that I need to pass.

oData Service from backend:

```
{
  "d" : {
    "__metadata" : {
      "id" : "http://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZOrders/HeaderSet('3898')",
      "uri" : "http://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZOrders/HeaderSet('3898')",
      "type" : "ZOrder.Header"
    },
    "CompanyID" : "W",
    "StockRoomID" : "A",
    "SalesDocument" : "3898",  


"ItemSet" : [
        {
          "__metadata" : {
            "id" : "http://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZOrders/ItemSet(SalesDocument='3898',SalesDocumentItem='000010')",
            "uri" : "http://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZOrders/ItemSet(SalesDocument='3898',SalesDocumentItem='000010')",
            "type" : "ZOrders.Item"
          },
          "SalesDocument" : "3898",
          "SalesDocumentItem" : "000010",  //Line item number
          "StockRoomID" : "A",
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
 buttonClick: function(event) {
    var sServiceURl = this.getOwnerComponent().getMetadata().getManifestEntry("sap.app").dataSources["ZOrders"].uri;
   this.OdataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sServiceURl);
   var model = vc.getView().getModel();

   var oEntry = {};
   oEntry.CompanyID = model.getProperty("/CompanyID");
   oEntry.StockRoomID = model.getProperty("/StockRoomID");
   oEntry.SalesDocument = model.getProperty("/SalesDocument");



    //Now want to pass items data to service so 
    //Creating an empty ItemSet array, pulling data from model.

    //But my logic is wrong here for sure. 
            var itemData = [];

            var itemsArray = v.getProperty("/ItemSet");

            for (var i = 0; i < itemsArray.results.length; i++) {
            itemData.push({
                    SalesDocument: itemsArray.results[i].SalesDocument,
                    SalesDocumentItem: itemsArray.results[i].SalesDocumentItem,
                    StockRoomID: itemsArray.results[i].StockRoomID,

                });

            }
            oEntry.ItemSet = itemData;

     this.OdataModel.create("/HeaderSet", oEntry, this._submitOrderSuccess.bind(this), this._submitOrderError.bind(this));
```

**Debugger - Header payload **

```
{  
   "CompanyID":"RSW0",
   "StockRoomID":"A200",
   "SalesDocument":"4053",
   "Return":"X",
   "Reason":"101",
   "ItemSet":[  
      {  
         "SalesDocument":"4053",
         "SalesDocumentItem":"000010",
         "StockRoomID":"A200",
         "ReturnItemFlag":"X",
         "QtyToReturn":"1.000"
      },
      {  
         "SalesDocument":"4053",
         "SalesDocumentItem":"000020",
         "StockRoomID":"A200",
         "ReturnItemFlag":"X",
         "QtyToReturn":"1.000"
      },
      {  
         "SalesDocument":"4053",
         "SalesDocumentItem":"000030",
         "StockRoomID":"A200",
         "ReturnItemFlag":"X",
         "QtyToReturn":"1.000"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Debugger - Response **

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "__metadata":{  
         "id":"https://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZORDER/HeaderSet('60000353')",
         "uri":"https://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZORDER/HeaderSet('60000353')",
         "type":"ZORDER.Header"
      },
      "CompanyID":"",
      "StockRoomID":"",
      "SalesDocument":"60000353",
      "ReferenceDoc":"",
      "AccountNumber":"",
      "PoNumber":"",
      "Message":"Return order 0060000353 has been created successfully",
      "OrderTotal":"0.00",
      "StockRoomName":"",
      "Return":"",
      "Reason":"",
      "Auth":"",
      "ItemSet":null,
      "HeaderCSDSet":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"https://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZORDER/HeaderSet('60000353')/HeaderCSDSet"
         }
      },
      "AddressSet":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"https://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZORDER/HeaderSet('60000353')/AddressSet"
         }
      },
      "GeneralCommentsSet":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"https://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZORDER/HeaderSet('60000353')/GeneralCommentsSet"
         }
      },
      "CreditCardSet":{  
         "__deferred":"uri":"https://.../sap/opu/odata/sap/ZORDER/HeaderSet('60000353')/CreditCardSet"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scenario of dependant Entity or Navigation property from Header to Item. Google "Deep Entity in SAPUI5 and oData for more understanding".

There is an error in your code where you have mentioned: "the logic is wrong".

Just add one line after the for loop:

```
oEntry.Items = ItemSet;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my controller after the line : "logic is wrong here for sure". I have also added the line as you told after for loop. Could you please review this code? Because, now I don't get any error. But the debugger does not stop at success function. In Network: under Header I see the payload and I can see the Itemset being passed. But in response tab in $batch, "ItemSet":null  is shown. for other sets atleast like this is shown:
"HeaderCSDSet": {
   "__deferred": {
    "uri": ".....sap/opu/odata/sap/ZOrders/HeaderSet('60000339')/HeaderCSDSet"
   }
  },

Comment: what is the response(status code) of the request ??

Comment: Can you share the debugger snapshot showing the complete "oEntry" ?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the debugger -- Header and Response. In Backend the order gets created correctly, but in debug mode the cursor does not stop at success breakpoint. Niether at error. I have also tried giving alerts but nothing comes up. Dunno where the cursor goes after .create call.